# Plotting selective data points on Orthographic map in D3js

Tags: d3.js

So I am making a draggable orthographic map using d3js V4. I need to plot large number of points on the map. But plotting all of them slows the dragging. I was thinking if I could just get the points for the visible coordinates and fetch the points again when dragging.

So basically, I would like to get max and min lat-lon pairs which are visible in the viewport, fetch and plot my data points according to these pairs. Once I drag the globe, I again get these new pairs and fetch and draw the new points on map.

I tried using getBBox and convert the x & y values into lat-lon pair using projection.invert and then fetch my data points according to these points, but the x & y values its giving seems incorrect (My svg element has a dynamic height and width but getBBox gives height and width as 600px, I assumed getBBox will give me x & y values for svg. Am I wrong in understanding this?)

Below is the code so far.

```
    var height=window.innerHeight*.8, width=(window.innerWidth<768)?500:window.innerWidth*0.7, sens = 0.25, scaleValue=window.innerWidth<768?150:300;
    var dataList={};

    var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
                .scale(scaleValue)
                .translate([width/2,height/2]);
    var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();
    var svgPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection).pointRadius( function(d,i) {
        return 1;
    });

    /*drag globe to view more*/
    var dragged = d3.drag()
        .subject(function() { 
            var pointOfDrag = projection.rotate(); 
            return {x: pointOfDrag[0] / sens, y: -pointOfDrag[1] / sens}; 
        })
        .on("drag", function() {
            var rotate = projection.rotate();
            projection.rotate([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens, rotate[2]]);
            //console.log(projection.invert([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens]));
            svg.selectAll("path.land").attr("d", svgPath);
            svg.selectAll("path.graticule").attr("d", svgPath);


            var bbox = svg.node().getBBox();
            var x1 = bbox.x;
            var y1 = bbox.y;
            var x2 = bbox.x+bbox.width;
            var y2 = bbox.y+bbox.height;

            var lonLat1 = projection.invert([x1, y1]);
            var lonLat2 = projection.invert([x2, y2]);
            getDataPoints(lonLat1, lonLat2);
            locations.selectAll("path.geo-node").attr("d", svgPath);
        });

    var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height",height).attr("width",width).call(dragged);
    var locations = svg.append('svg:g')
        .attr('id', 'locations');

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", svgPath);

    var mapData={}, dataPoints={};

    $.when( $.ajax( "/world" )).done(function ( v1) {
        drawGlobe(v1);
    });

    var drawGlobe = function(map){
        svg.selectAll("path.land")
            .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "land")
            .attr("d", svgPath);

        svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
            .datum(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features)
            .attr("class", "land")
            .attr("d", svgPath);
        var bbox = svg.node().getBBox();
        var x1 = bbox.x;
        var y1 = bbox.y;
        var x2 = bbox.x+bbox.width;
        var y2 = bbox.y+bbox.height;
        var lonLat1 = projection.invert([x1, y1]);
        var lonLat2 = projection.invert([x2, y2]);
        getDataPoints(lonLat1, lonLat2);
    };
    var drawPoints=function(dataList){
        var circles = locations.selectAll('path')
            .data(dataList)
            .enter()
            .append('svg:path')
            .datum(function(d) {
               return {type: "Point", coordinates: [d.coord["Lon"], d.coord["Lat"]]};
            })
            .attr('class', 'geo-node')
            .attr('d', svgPath);
    }
```

Can anybody guide me in the correct direction?

**EDIT:**

Added a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ya6o3cgIbWZLCNcJlZeo?p=preview) with smaller data-set

Comment: How many points are we talking about? Also, setting up a working demo to fiddle around with will be of great help.

Comment: I am reading the data points from a json file. It contains around 10k points. Actually I had set up a backend to read file and process data, thats the reason couldn't give a fiddle link. But will try to do it and get back here.

Comment: Hey, I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ya6o3cgIbWZLCNcJlZeo?p=preview) with smaller data-set.

Comment: This reminds me of https://earth.nullschool.net. In addition to using canvas instead of SVG, the points and animations are hidden while dragging or zooming. The code is publicly available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cambecc/earth) and offers scores of inspirations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew about [earth](https://earth.nullschool.net/). The thing is the data i use is plain lat-lon based but I guess he (Cameron Beccario) uses data arcs. I had gone through the code, but it was overwhelming for me and I understood bits and pieces only. So, I had gone ahead and did things the way I understood, i.e. using "svg" and plotting data points in each "g". Since you pointed out about using canvas instead of svg, I tried with canvas as well but I am stuck with displaying points and rotating points with map rotation. :(